# Special price calculating tier price in Magento

Tags: magento

hope anyone can help me with this problem.

Here is the problem. I need to displa/ output a special calculatet price in the tier price output on the Product page.

For example. I have

Buy 2 for 15,99 € each and save 6%
Buy 3 for ..........

I need to display ...

Buy 2 for 15,99 € **(0,15)** each and save 6%
Buy 3 for ..........

**Outputt = 15,99 / 100 = (0,15)**

(0,15) = unit price

for 15,99 € the customer buy 100 units. So he can see the unit price.

I think i must create a formula to calculate it in  tierprices.phtml .... But don´t know how.

```
<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $this->__('Buy %1$s for %2$s (%3$s incl. tax) each', $_price['price_qty'], $_price['formated_price'], $_price['formated_price_incl_tax']) ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Hope somone can help me with this problem...

Thanks

Comment: You just want to display this special price or actually use the special price? If you just do it in the phtml it will only display it. When someone adds it to cart they will not get the special price.

Comment: I want just display that price. Its just a calculation per unit. In one product the customer buy are like 100 units. So the customer can see witch price is per unit.

Comment: If i do $_finalPriceInclTax /100 it shows the final price divided with 100. But what i must do to divide $_price['formated_price'] and $_price['formated_price_incl_tax'] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending houres in this finding the answear i keept trying to finde a solution by me self. Hope this help someone else to.

**number_format($_price['price'] /100, 3)**